# ADA - precondition in 'class

Tags: ada

I'm trying to compile this code :

```
function valid(a:Toto'Class; t: Titi) return Boolean with Pre'Class => fonction(a);
```

GNAT says "aspect "pre'class" can only be specified for a primitive operation of a tagged private"

I guess it's because of the Toto'Class but how could I make it work ?

Comment: By removing the `’Class`. I was going to post more extensively as an answer, but found I am quite unclear on the difference between `Pre’Class` and plain `Pre`.

Comment: Is `Titi` a tagged type?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `Pre'Class` and `Post'Class`, I believe, is to specify preconditions that apply even when a subprogram is overridden.

```
package Pack1 is
    type Base_Type is tagged record ... end record;
    procedure Operation (Obj : Base_Type) with Pre'Class => [condition];
end Pack1;
```

What this means is that if the condition is met, then `Operation` is allowed, even if derived types impose other conditions.  Suppose a procedure uses this operation on a `Base_Type'Class` object:

```
procedure Something_Else (Obj : Base_Type'Class) is
begin
    -- check to make sure the condition is true
    Obj.Operation;
end Something_Else;
```

`Something_Else` doesn't know what the actual type of `Obj` is.  But it can still be assured that if the `Pre'Class` condition is `true`, then `Operation` can be performed (i.e. it satisfies the preconditions).  If the condition were just `Pre => [condition]`, it could not be assured that this would work, because `Obj`'s actual type could be a derived type, and `Operation` could be overridden for that derived type with a more restrictive condition, and the condition on the overriding `Operation` would be the one that is checked (since the call would *dispatch* to the overriding `Operation`).  With `Pre'Class`, both conditions are checked, and the operation is allowable if either condition is true (thus a derived type can make things less restrictive).  But the important thing is that `Something_Else` is relying on the contract that, if the `Pre'Class` condition is true, then `Operation` is allowable.

However, none of this matters if `Operation` can't be overridden.  In your example, since `Valid`'s parameter is `Toto'Class`, and since (I assume) `Titi` is not a tagged type, `Valid` is not a primitive operation and therefore is not a dispatching operation.

```
procedure Another_Procedure (Obj : Toto'Class; T : Titi) is
begin
    if Obj.Valid(T) then
        ...
    end if;
end Another_Procedure;
```

When `Another_Procedure` calls `Valid`, it will always call the `Valid` that you wrote; it will never dispatch to a different `Valid`, no matter what type `Obj` actually is.  `Valid` is not a dispatching function.  Because of that, there's no point in putting a *class-wide*  precondition on it.  So the language disallows it.

**Note:** In a simple case where there is just a base type and a derived type, not a chain of types, `Pre'Class` means that an operation can be performed if the condition **or** any precondition on the derived type succeeds.  `Post'Class` means that a subprogram meets the condition if the condition **and** any postcondition on the derived type succeed.